# android studio SQLite DB image saving locally and syncing later on remote server

Tags: java, xml

I want to  browse and capture image through a button (naming upload) then i need to save the selected image in to sqlite database android,  and then save that image on remote server db (sync)... 
dont know the method and steps to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this flow:

1. Using an intent, capture an image and store it inside your local storage.
2. Save the path of the image into local db.
3. When you want to upload the image(s), just retrieve the file from the path you have.

manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
```

Note: Please avoid saving image into local db it may cause OOM exception.

For camera intent, please refer this link: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics